# Set below query into asc or desc order?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
over
     (
        ORDER BY
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_id' THEN Country_id END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_name' THEN Country_name END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_region' THEN Country_region END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_area' THEN Country_area END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_Population' THEN Country_Population END,
        CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_gdp' THEN Country_gdp END
     )as num ,* From Country_Profile123 ) as tbl
      WHERE num BETWEEN @column AND @column1
```

I solved half of the problem (that is the paging and sorting), what I'm trying to do now is the sorting order.

Comment: what is your question ? plus this is om mysql, sql-server ?

Comment: I AM USING SQL SERVER MANAGE CODE.. 
I WANT TO DO PAGING AND SORTING. WHICH IS DONE..BUT REMAINING IS SORTING ORDER WHICH IS I WANT TO DO.. 
SO I WANT HELP....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
over
     (
        ORDER BY
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_id' THEN Country_id DESC END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_id_asc' THEN Country_id ASC END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_name' THEN Country_name DESC END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_name_asc' THEN Country_name ASC END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_region' THEN Country_region DESC END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_region_asc' THEN Country_region ASC END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_area' THEN Country_area DESC END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_area_asc' THEN Country_area ASC END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_Population' THEN Country_Population DESC  END,
          CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_Population_asc' THEN Country_Population ASC END,
        CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_gdp' THEN Country_gdp DESC END
        CASE WHEN @SortExpression ='Country_gdp_asc' THEN Country_gdp ASC END
     )as num ,* From Country_Profile123 ) as tbl
      WHERE num BETWEEN @column AND @column1
```

Comment: That won't work. You can't apply the sort order to the value in the case, you have to put it in the order by outside the case.

Answer (score 3):

Use a single case statement instead of repeating the same case statement for each possible value:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
  over (
    ORDER BY
      CASE @SortExpression
        WHEN 'Country_id' THEN Country_id
        WHEN 'Country_name' THEN Country_name
        WHEN 'Country_region' THEN Country_region
        WHEN 'Country_area' THEN Country_area
        WHEN 'Country_Population' THEN Country_Population
        WHEN 'Country_gdp' THEN Country_gdp
      END
  ) as num, * From Country_Profile123
) as tbl
WHERE num BETWEEN @column AND @column1
```

Applying sort order is a bit trickier. You can't apply the direction to the value, so you need a first hand case and a second hand case with different directions:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
  over (
    ORDER BY
      CASE @SortExpression
        WHEN 'Country_id' THEN Country_id
        WHEN 'Country_name' THEN Country_name
        WHEN 'Country_region' THEN Country_region
        WHEN 'Country_area' THEN Country_area
        WHEN 'Country_Population' THEN Country_Population
        WHEN 'Country_gdp' THEN Country_gdp
        ELSE 0
      END,
      CASE @SortExpression
        WHEN 'Country_id_desc' THEN Country_id
        WHEN 'Country_name_desc' THEN Country_name
        WHEN 'Country_region_desc' THEN Country_region
        WHEN 'Country_area_desc' THEN Country_area
        WHEN 'Country_Population_desc' THEN Country_Population
        WHEN 'Country_gdp_desc' THEN Country_gdp
        ELSE 0
      END DESC
  ) as num, * From Country_Profile123
) as tbl
WHERE num BETWEEN @column AND @column1
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

This error is coming. when i was run your query

Comment: @sikender: Each `case` can only handle one data type. You need one separate `case` for each data type.